# Action de mettre quelque chose à l'horaire

Tags: traduction, québec

En anglais, on peut utiliser le verbe : "To schedule" qui implique de mettre quelque chose à l'horaire (ou à son calendrier, peu importe).

En français, si je ne m'abuse "céduler" est un anglicisme, qui n'est donc pas valide.

Existe-t-il un verbe équivalent à "schedule" en français?

Par exemple, on pourrait dire en anglais : "I scheduled a meeting on monday morning" qui se traduirait par... "J'ai ... une réunion lundi matin". J'utilise l'anglicisme "booké" mais j'aimerais avoir le bon terme à utiliser..

Comment: Although it’s mentioned below that there is no/very little ambiguity in French, the ambiguity-causing nuance mentioned by @RiguefortUltraquaillette (was the meeting scheduled “**on** Monday” or “**for** Monday”) is a very real & important one to be aware of in English:  “We’ll schedule it **on** Monday **for** sometime later in the week.”  The lack of ambiguity in French + my anglo-ness surely explains why I would (perhaps wrongly) use and (until now) expect to see “pour” in the following: “On va le prévoir lundi (l’ajouter au calendrier lundi) **pour** plus tard dans la semaine.

Comment: Personnellement, je n'ai jamais entendu l'expression "mettre quelque chose à l'horaire" en France. Je comprend grâce au contexte, mais où avez vous vu cette expression ? Suis-je le seul que ça choque ?

Comment: @Random C'est peut-être une expression québecoise, mais je ne peux pas le formuler autrement puisque c'est justement cette phrase là que je cherche à remplacer par un verbe..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En plus de *planifier*, on peut utiliser *programmer* :

> J'ai programmé une réunion lundi matin.

Ou bien, par ellipse:

> J'ai une réunion lundi matin.
>
> Je suis en réunion lundi matin.

On peut aussi indiquer si on est l'instigateur ou pas:

> J'organise une réunion lundi matin.
>
> Je participerai/J'assisterai à une réunion lundi matin.

Dans une forme moins littérale, on peut dire:

> J'ai réservé mon lundi matin pour une réunion.

Answer (score 5):

On peut utiliser le verbe **planifier**

Par exemple : Cet agenda vous permettra de planifier des rendez-vous ou des événements à une date ou une heure donnée.

> Definition:
>
> Organiser à l'avance son temps, ses activités selon un certain plan :
> *Planifier ses vacances*.
>
> Organiser à l'avance quelque chose, l'avoir
> dans son plan : *Planifier l'heure d'arrivée du ministre*.

Comment: Je me demande si planifier n'est pas plus : "Souhaiter mettre à l'horaire" plutôt que de le faire? Qu'en penses-tu?

Comment: @TopinFrassi - Planifier s'utilise pour une intention de faire quelque chose à un moment donné (*tout en envisageant des possibilités de modifications selon les événements*) et aussi pour fixer une date et/ou une heure précise.

Comment: Justement, je ne cherche pas "une intention de..." mais bien l'action de le faire ou de l'avoir fait. Est-ce que "Planifier" s'appliquerait quand même?

Comment: @TopinFrassi -  "I scheduled a meeting on monday morning" se traduit parfaitement par "J'ai planifié un rendez-vous lundi matin". Je manque même d'idée pour trouver une autre traduction.

Comment: @RiguefortUltraquaillette Il n'y a pas vraiment d'ambiguïté. Tout le monde comprendra que lundi matin se rapporte au rendez-vous, pas à la planification sauf si cette phrase est une réponse à la question improbable « Quand as-tu planifié un rendez-vous ? ». Pour signifier que l'action s'est déroulée le lundi, on dira plutôt « Lundi matin, j'ai planifié un rendez-vous ».

Comment: Il n'y a aucune ambiguïté pour moi. Le temps du verbe "planifier" indique quand l'action de réflexion se déroule, et le jour indique la date du rendez-vous.

Answer (score 3):

Prévoir est aussi largement utilisé:

> J'ai prévu une réunion lundi matin. (si je suis l'instigateur)

ou

> Une réunion a été prévue lundi matin.

Answer (score 0):

En Suisse, on utiliserait le verbe **agender** qui a exactement ce sens (*inscrire quelque chose dans son agenda*), mais je ne crois pas qu'il soit utilisé ailleurs.

Comment: Ce terme qu'on ne trouve pas à ma connaissance dans le dictionnaire conviendrait parfaitement. Sans doute couvert par le secret bancaire, il a du être bloqué à la frontière franco-suisse : c'est la première fois que je l'entends :).